# Multi-lined Label in Scala

Tags: swing, scala, scala-swing

Short question, hopefully simple solution:

I've got my own renderer for a `ListView`, nothing too fancy, it just connects a `Label` and and `Icon`. My questions is, so far, the Label ignores my "\n"s. How can I change that? I'd like to have two lines for the information I present.

Thanks for listening.

Comment: Note that this issue is not Scala specific. It works the same way as in Java 6, so you can use any resources about Swing you can find.

Answer (score 3):

Use html for your Label. Like this: `new JLabel("<html>line 1<br>line 2</html>");`

Comment: If it is a size issue try this approach: myLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200)); You can make it more sophisticated if you getFontMetrics() and calculate the size.

Comment: Nope, it is not the size, there is plenty of room - it was even enough to swallow the \n and show both in one line.

Comment: Here is another option: new JLabel("<html><table><tr><td>a line</td></tr><tr><td>another line</td></tr></table></html>");

Comment: Hrm nope... maybe it is because I cannot use the `JLabel`, it has to be a Scala Label. But thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> import java.awt._
scala> import javax.swing._
scala> val frame = new JFrame()
scala> frame.setVisible(true)
scala> frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300))
scala> val l = new JLabel("abc\nefg")
scala> frame.getContentPane.add(l)
scala> frame.pack
scala> l.setText("<html>abc<br>def</html>")
```

Using \n doesn't work, but `<html>abc<br>def</html>` does.